# Not recognised as an csv file in Weka

Tags: weka

Weka told me that `112 Problem encountered on line 2`

Here attached my line one and line two.

> ,Unnamed:
>   0,id,timestamp,derived_0,derived_1,derived_2,derived_3,derived_4,fundamental_0,fundamental_1,fundamental_2,fundamental_3,fundamental_5,fundamental_6,fundamental_7,fundamental_8,fundamental_9,fundamental_10,fundamental_11,fundamental_12,fundamental_13,fundamental_14,fundamental_15,fundamental_16,fundamental_17,fundamental_18,fundamental_19,fundamental_20,fundamental_21,fundamental_22,fundamental_23,fundamental_24,fundamental_25,fundamental_26,fundamental_27,fundamental_28,fundamental_29,fundamental_30,fundamental_31,fundamental_32,fundamental_33,fundamental_34,fundamental_35,fundamental_36,fundamental_37,fundamental_38,fundamental_39,fundamental_40,fundamental_41,fundamental_42,fundamental_43,fundamental_44,fundamental_45,fundamental_46,fundamental_47,fundamental_48,fundamental_49,fundamental_50,fundamental_51,fundamental_52,fundamental_53,fundamental_54,fundamental_55,fundamental_56,fundamental_57,fundamental_58,fundamental_59,fundamental_60,fundamental_61,fundamental_62,fundamental_63,technical_0,technical_1,technical_2,technical_3,technical_5,technical_6,technical_7,technical_9,technical_10,technical_11,technical_12,technical_13,technical_14,technical_16,technical_17,technical_18,technical_19,technical_20,technical_21,technical_22,technical_24,technical_25,technical_27,technical_28,technical_29,technical_30,technical_31,technical_32,technical_33,technical_34,technical_35,technical_36,technical_37,technical_38,technical_39,technical_40,technical_41,technical_42,technical_43,technical_44,y
>
> 1,1,11,0,0.0147646842524,-0.0380642190576,-0.017424877733,0.320652008057,-0.0341343283653,0.00441261287779,0.114285111427,-0.210184767842,0.21628062427,0.0967497378588,0.0820423513651,-0.224383309484,-0.0855291187763,0.0247628260404,-0.062337320298,-0.202246636152,1.74669158459,-0.187505245209,-0.0346640832722,-0.135176599026,0.30556216836,0.0275948308408,-0.2087456882,0.11851990968,-0.123511128128,0.113818153739,,-0.115836977959,0.0282817184925,0.0765652507544,-0.217346027493,0.100053846836,0.358807504177,0.057504683733,0.0257191713899,-0.141338810325,2.2934756279,0.0249454267323,0.388208180666,-0.240926593542,-0.126231744885,-0.131619036198,0.232267677784,-0.00145528209396,-0.489862799644,0.0173165425658,0.0273206215352,0.334182590246,0.113512799144,0.111536450684,-0.179379090667,0.221287444234,-0.0918863341212,,0.107981853187,0.548687160015,-0.160078704357,-0.281368345022,0.0639325976372,-0.235643029213,-0.205082535744,-0.194349050522,-0.365185618401,0.0419283285737,-0.044906552881,-0.039078630507,-0.0750000029802,-0.28041779995,,,-2.0,,,-2.0,-0.159431889653,,0.0,-2.0,,0.00431661866605,0.0,,-2.0,,-0.399520397186,0.0,-0.309356480837,-0.5,,,0.154613018036,,0.0,0.0,,,,0.5,0.232154071331,0.0255901403725,,,,-0.273607432842,,,-2.0,,-0.00124013668392

Comment: try this https://csvlint.io/ to check if your csv file is ok

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with Weka's ARFF converter and I could not get things to work even with [LibreOffice hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310033/164148) or TSV hack (to save as TSV but rename it as CSV) but then I found `foreign` package in R with `write.arff` function. It works so that

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
library(data.table)
a<-fread("YourData.csv")
write.arff(a,file="~/YourLocation.arff")
```

and further information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.arff.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem first by simply opening the data file in LibreOffice, viewing it there such that it looks correct, autofixing the input then and choose *Save as* as CSV. 
Weka considered the file this way correctly.

However, I am thinking about a terminal approach for this in the related thread [How to standardise this nonstandard CSV file for Weka?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381754/16920.)

Comment: I tried this on my file but did not work `invalid stream header` error. I also tried saving CSV as tab-separated file and renaming it as csv but not working.

Comment: @hhh We need to state clearly the LibreOffice work process to study this further.

Comment: Or you can just use R's foreign package as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655529/164148).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried this alternative solution which worked for me :

1. upload your .csv file to https://csvlint.io/
2. after uploading is done click on validate
3. though it gives your .csv as a valid file, click on the "Download Standardised CSV" button
4. use this downloaded .csv file and add it to WEKA